# Get values from dynamic table and draws it with google charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to get the values from the dynamic table and after that I want draw it with Google charts, but the code doesn't work, I can't understand what's the problem. I think the problem is related to the method that I use to get the value from the table, but I'm not sure.

When I get the values and I try to draw it, Google returns the following error:

Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Can anyone help me to fix my code please?

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/macco_cl/qaogs3sx/

```js
var theTable, theTableBody
var myForm = document.forms.myForm; 
var png =  document.getElementById("png");

function init() {
    theTable = (document.all) ? document.all.myTABLE : 
        document.getElementById("myTABLE")
    theTableBody = theTable.tBodies[0]
}
function appendRow(form) {
    insertTableRow(form, -1)
}
function addRow(form) {
    insertTableRow(form, form.insertIndex.value)
}
function insertTableRow(form, where) {
    var now = new Date()
    var nowData = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), 
        now.getMilliseconds()]
    clearBGColors()
    var newCell
    var newRow = theTableBody.insertRow(where)
    for (var i = 0; i < nowData.length; i++) {
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(i)
        newCell.innerHTML = nowData[i]
        newCell.style.backgroundColor = "salmon"
    }
    updateRowCounters(form)
}
function removeRow(form) {
    theTableBody.deleteRow(form.deleteIndex.value)
    updateRowCounters(form)
}
function insertTHEAD(form) {
    var THEADData = ["Hours","Minutes","Seconds","Milliseconds"]
    var newCell
    var newTHEAD = theTable.createTHead()
    newTHEAD.id = "myTHEAD"
    var newRow = newTHEAD.insertRow(-1)
    for (var i = 0; i < THEADData.length; i++) {
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(i)
        newCell.innerHTML = THEADData[i]
    }
    updateRowCounters(form)
    form.addTHEAD.disabled = true
    form.deleteTHEAD.disabled = false
}
function removeTHEAD(form) {
    theTable.deleteTHead()    
    updateRowCounters(form)
    form.addTHEAD.disabled = false
    form.deleteTHEAD.disabled = true
}
function insertTFOOT(form) {
    var TFOOTData = ["Hours","Minutes","Seconds","Milliseconds"]
    var newCell
    var newTFOOT = theTable.createTFoot()
    newTFOOT.id = "myTFOOT"
    var newRow = newTFOOT.insertRow(-1)
    for (var i = 0; i < TFOOTData.length; i++) {
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(i)
        newCell.innerHTML = TFOOTData[i]
    }
    updateRowCounters(form)
    form.addTFOOT.disabled = true
    form.deleteTFOOT.disabled = false
}

function removeTFOOT(form) {
    theTable.deleteTFoot()    
    updateRowCounters(form)
    form.addTFOOT.disabled = false
    form.deleteTFOOT.disabled = true
}
function insertCaption(form) {
    var captionData = form.captionText.value
    var newCaption = theTable.createCaption()
    newCaption.innerHTML = captionData
    form.addCaption.disabled = true
    form.deleteCaption.disabled = false
}
function removeCaption(form) {
    theTable.deleteCaption()    
    form.addCaption.disabled = false
    form.deleteCaption.disabled = true
}
// housekeeping functions
function updateRowCounters(form) {
    var sel1 = form.insertIndex
    var sel2 = form.deleteIndex
    sel1.options.length = 0
    sel2.options.length = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < theTableBody.rows.length; i++) {
        sel1.options[i] = new Option(i, i)
        sel2.options[i] = new Option(i, i)
    }
    form.removeRowBtn.disabled = (i==0)
}
function clearBGColors() {
    for (var i = 0; i < theTableBody.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < theTableBody.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            theTableBody.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = ""        
        }
    }
}

function GetCellValues() {
  
        var table = document.getElementById("myTABLE");
       
        for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
            for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
                alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
            }
        }
        
        return table;
}

function mostra() {
 document.getElementById("chart_div").style.display="block";
}

function nascondi() {
 document.getElementById("chart_div").style.display="none";
} 
 
function finestra(){

  if(tf == true){
   window.open("pngbar.html");
   //document.getElementById("chart_div").style.display="none";
  }
}

function setDati(){
  
    
  //if(png.checked)
  // tf = true;
  //else
  // tf = false;
   
  drawRightY();
  
}
 
function drawRightY() {
  tf = false;
  var valori = GetCellValues(); 
  
  
  var f = new Array();
  
    
  for (var i=0;i<valori.rows.length;i++) {
   f[i]=new Array();
    for (var j=0;j<valori.rows[i].cells.length;j++) {
     f[i][j]= valori.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
     
    }   
  }
  
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(f,true);

      var options = {
        chart: {
         // title: z,
        },
        hAxis: {
  
          minValue: 0,
        },
        vAxis: {

        },
 
        axes: {
          y: {
            0: {side: 'right'}
          }
        }
      }; 
   if (tf == false){
    var material = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    material.draw(data, options);
   }
    if (tf == true) {
     var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
     var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chart_div);

    // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
   
     });

     options = {width: 1920, height: 1080}
     chart.draw(data, options);
     document.getElementById("chart_div").style.display="none";
     window.open(chart.getImageURI());
   
  }
 
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Modifying Table Cell Content</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
THEAD {background-color:lightyellow; font-weight:bold}
TFOOT {background-color:lightgreen; font-weight:bold}
#myTABLE {background-color:bisque}
</STYLE>
 <SCRIPT src="funzioni.js"></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRightY());

</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="init(),nascondi()">
<H1>Modifying Tables</H1>
<HR>
<FORM NAME="controls">
<FIELDSET>
<LEGEND>Add/Remove Rows</LEGEND>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLSPACING=20><TR>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Append 1 Row" 
    onClick="appendRow(this.form)"></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Insert 1 Row" onClick="addRow(this.form)"> at index: 
    <SELECT NAME="insertIndex">
        <OPTION VALUE="0">0
    </SELECT></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="removeRowBtn" VALUE="Delete 1 Row" DISABLED 
    onClick="removeRow(this.form)"> at index: 
    <SELECT NAME="deleteIndex">
        <OPTION VALUE="0">0
    </SELECT></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FIELDSET>
<FIELDSET>
<LEGEND>Add/Remove THEAD and TFOOT</LEGEND>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLSPACING=20><TR>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="addTHEAD" VALUE="Insert THEAD" 
    onClick="insertTHEAD(this.form)"><BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="deleteTHEAD" VALUE="Remove THEAD" DISABLED 
        onClick="removeTHEAD(this.form)">
</TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="addTFOOT" VALUE="Insert TFOOT" 
    onClick="insertTFOOT(this.form)"><BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="deleteTFOOT" VALUE="Remove TFOOT" DISABLED 
        onClick="removeTFOOT(this.form)">
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FIELDSET>
<FIELDSET>
<LEGEND>Add/Remove Caption</LEGEND>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLSPACING=20><TR>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="addCaption" VALUE="Add Caption" 
    onClick="insertCaption(this.form)"></TD>
<TD>Text: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="captionText" SIZE=40 VALUE="Sample Caption">
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="deleteCaption" VALUE="Delete Caption" DISABLED 
    onClick="removeCaption(this.form)"></TD>
    
<TD><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Prendi valori" VALUE="get"
    onClick="GetCellValues()"></TD>

</TR>
</TABLE>
</FIELDSET>
<!-- PNG<input type="checkbox" id="png" value="false" />-->
    <input type="button" value="Draw Chart" onclick="mostra(),setDati()" />
  
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
 
  <div id="chart_div"></div>

</FORM>
<HR>
<TABLE ID="myTABLE" CELLPADDING=10 BORDER=1>
<TBODY>
</TABLE>


   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You should set this up in a JSFiddle so that we can test and play with it.

Comment: I add the link to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to narrow down your questions and post only related code.

The problem you have is you're not converting your HTML Table values from strings to numbers when you add the values from the table to your "dataArray", which causes the whole input to try to represent strings with numbers.

I modified your array building loop, and added `if(i > 0)` (if it's not the first row (the headings) anymore). Whole loop now looks like:

```
    for (var i=0;i<valori.rows.length;i++) {
        f[i]=new Array();
            for (var j=0;j<valori.rows[i].cells.length;j++) {
                if(i > 0){
                    f[i][j]= Number(valori.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
                }else{
                    f[i][j]= valori.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
                }
        }           
    }
```

and it now works like a charm.

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/qaogs3sx/2/).

Comment: thanks for your help, now I drawn the Chart but column Hour doesn't appear moreover when I add  two or more rows, the chart doesn't add these rows as bars.